# MySQL SELECT when value doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, select

I am currently doing a query such as

```
"SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeValue=0"
```

There are cases where this does not exist. Is there a method for determining if the select actually found the data without checking that each returned value is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the data without checking that each returned value is empty?

If there are no rows matching the criteria, then no result set or table would be returned. So, there is no need for this.

You can use the `IF EXISTS (Select Query)` to see if there were any results matching the criteria and perform your subsequent operations.

Comment: I have a repeatable situation when I perform a select on a value that does not exist in the database, then call mysql_num_rows and it does not return 0. What am I missing here?

Comment: mysql_real_query also returns 0 (not error) when performing a select where the value does not exist.

Comment: MySQL wouldn't throw an error if there are no matches to a given filter. So, the behavior of MySQL is correct and expected. Checking on the PHP equivalent of `no results found for query in mysql`...

Comment: From this manual page at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php, it seems mysql_num_rows should be 0 if there are no matching records for a query. Not sure why it's not 0 in your case :(

Comment: Hmm, well maybe I'm messing up somehow. I'll dig into it more. Thanks for the help :)